# Posting data from multiple forms based on action

Tags: php, javascript, forms, http, dynamic

I have two different forms on one page that dynamically generate inputs. One is used for text inputs and by pressing a button(I'll call this form 1) another textbox appers. The other adds users to be notified. When a button is pressed a user is added to the list(I'll call this form 2).

Say I have 3 text boxes generated on form 1, if I try to add another user with form 2 all of the textboxes from form 1 disappear because the data from form 1 isn't being posted.

Here's how the two forms are called

```
<form method="post">
<?
$friends = new common_functions();
$friends->add_friends($added_friends); //this is in common functions - also used for assistance invites
?>
<br>
</form>


<form method="post">
<br>
<?
$register = new common_functions(); 
$register->register_tasks($j, $reg_description, $reg_num);
?>
</form>
<?
```

When I change it so these are both posted at the same time (instead of individually as it currently is), the individual forms don't work correctly.

**To sum it up, is there any way to tell a form to post its data even when a submit button isn't pressed? Something like onaction(post data from other form...)**

This is from form 2. If I remove the method from this then I can't properly delete items from the list.

```
if(count($added_friends) > 0){
        ?>
        <table width="200">
        <col width="150">
        <th>Name</th><th>Remove</th>
        <?
        $count = count($added_friends);
        for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++){
            if($added_friends[$i] == NULL){
                $count = $count;
            }
            $friend = $added_friends[$i];
            ?>

            <!-- allows a user to remove invited friends -->
            <form method="post">
            <tr><td><? echo $friend; ?></td><td><input type="submit" name="remove_friend" value="X"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="remove_name" value="<? echo $friend; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="added_friends" value="<? echo implode(',',$added_friends); ?>"/></td></tr>               </form>
            </form>
            <?
        }
        ?>
        </table>

    <?
    }
```

Comment: "don't work correctly" how? do the fields use the same name between each form? you get mangled data? the form kicks your dog and drinks your beer?

Comment: I gave a short explanation above....Say I have 3 text boxes generated on form 1, if I try to add another user with form 2 all of the textboxes from form 1 disappear because the data from form 1 isn't being posted.

Comment: @MarcB lol, why you gotta bring the dog into it? This a country song?

Comment: @user1123815: forms don't magically suck up the entire page. only the fields within the `<form>` block that the submit button is within will get posted. if you want "other" forms posted as well, use one huge form that does cover the entire page.

Comment: @user1123815: You could use javascript to post the form via ajax. It's hard to understand without seeing your common_functions class

Comment: @PastorBones It's probably better that I don't post the common_functions because several hundred lines of code would just complicate things even more...Can I do something like onaction(post form1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain of you're exact needs, but for something like this I would use [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com). There are other such javascript frameworks like [angularjs](http://angularjs.org) and [backbone](http://backbonejs.org) (google for more).

Here is a simple knockoutjs [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V5JdU/2/) displaying the functionality you're looking for.

#### Javascript

```
var viewModel = function(){
    this.values = ko.observableArray();
    this.invited = ko.observableArray();
    this.addValue = function(){
        var txt = $('#form1 input').val();
        this.values.push(txt);
    }.bind(this);
    this.addInvite = function(){
        var txt = $('#form2 input').val();
        this.invited.push(txt);
    }.bind(this);
    this.sendData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'www.blah.com/blahblah',
            data: { text: this.values(), invited: this.invited() } 
        });   
    }.bind(this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

#### HTML

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form1">
        <input type="text" />
        <button data-bind="click: addValue">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="valueList" data-bind="visible: values().length > 0">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: values">
            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
        <input type="text" />
        <button data-bind="click: addInvite">Invite</button>
    </div>
    <div id="inviteList" data-bind="visible: invited().length > 0">
        <ul data-bind="foreach: invited">
            <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: sendData">Save</button>
</body>
```

As you can see knockoutjs relies on **JQuery** being available, but this also gives you access to JQuery's ajax functionality. This allows you to send the data via ajax. I <3 knockoutjs for it's simplicity and users love the magic it provides. *You'll have to modify the ajax options to suit your needs, of course*

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the advice. This seems like it may work. I'm going to look into it further.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to turn you on to new methods of reaching the real-time interactivity that you're looking for.